# Dimension of the nilradical nil( g ) of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra g

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

The nilradical nil(g) of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra g is its maximal nilpotent ideal, which exists because the sum of any two nilpotent ideals is nilpotent.
How to prove that $dim(nil(g))$ at least $1/2 dim(g)$?

Comment: This is quite false, e.g. any semisimple Lie algebra has trivial nilradical.

Comment: Truth. Well, what if algebra is not semisimple?

Answer (score 3):

The correct statement is, the the nilradical of a *solvable* Lie algebra $L$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero satisfies
$$
\dim {\rm nil}(L)\ge \frac{1}{2}\dim (L).
$$
Actually, more is true, we have
$$
\dim {\rm nil}(L)\ge \frac{1}{2}(\dim (L)+\dim (L^{(2)}))
$$

Reference: [Snobl](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.762.8712&rep=rep1&type=pdf), $(18)$, page $8$.

Comment: Humm! thank very murch.